Purge all data older than xx without using DML?
I have an Oracle database, I want to purge any data older than 365 days from all tables.
All the tables in this DB doesn't have timestamps in them. So I couldn't develop a SQL based solution.
Oracle logs all transactions occurring in a database.
So I was wondering if there is a setting in Oracle to configure it to purge all records which didn't change in the last xx days.

No, there's no non-DML/DDL way to purge data, and nothing that works database-wide. You wouldn't want to do all those deletes even if you could recognize the proper rows. If you have very large tables, add a date col to them and partition them, and you can drop old partitions efficiently without incurring the huge cost of deletes. Don't bother with small tables.

Okay thanks. And thanks for the alternative suggestion, I will look into it.


So I was wondering if there is a setting in Oracle to configure it to purge all records which didn't change in the last xx days.

No, there is no such setting.
Add a timestamp column to your tables and then setup a scheduled job to run each day (or whatever interval you feel is appropriate) to delete rows from each table when the timestamp is older than TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -12)).

Just adding timestamp wouldn't suffice right, also have to take care of the order of purge... depending upon the table relationships

@Hirak That is left as an implementation detail of "then setup a scheduled job to run each day to delete rows from each table" which the user can choose best how to implement. Yes, you would have to be careful to respect referential constraints and not to leave orphaned data but the question lacks any such implementation details which would allow a more concrete answer.
